# Fecha actual con NODEJS

Tags: nodejs

tengo inconvenientes con mi codigo, quiero obtener la fecha actual en NODE

```
    console.log(new Date(Date.now()))
```

pero me regresa una fecha diferente, nada que ver con mi zona horaria, fecha actual 2022-08-09 y me muestra la fecha despues de 10 hrs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seria de mucha ayuda su aportacion, gracias.

Comment: Donde se esta ejecutando esta app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te voy a mostrar 3 formas diferentes de establecer la zona horaria predeterminada en Node.js.

### Usando la variable de entorno TZ

Se puede configurar la variable de entorno **TZ** de esta manera:

```javascript
process.env.TZ = 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'; // GMT -03:00
console.log(new Date().toString())

// Salida: 'Wed Aug 10 2022 03:37:26 GMT-0300 (hora estándar de Argentina)'
```

La lista completa de *time zones* está [acá](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

### Usando método toLocaleString

```javascript
const date = new Date();

console.log(
  date.toLocaleString('es-AR', {
    timeZone: 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires',
    dateStyle: 'medium',
    timeStyle: 'medium',
  }),
);
// Salida: '10 ago 2022 03:52:02'
```

### Usando un paquete de terceros

Instalar **set-tz**:

`npm i set-tz @types/set-tz`

Implementarlo de la siguiente manera:

```javascript
import setTZ from 'set-tz';
setTZ('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires')

console.log(new Date().toString())

// Salida: 'Wed Aug 10 2022 03:37:26 GMT-0300 (hora estándar de Argentina)'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es exactamente lo que necesitaba, fue de mucha ayuda. :3